# Pygame sprite not deleting itself

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am making a game and when the sprite "Bomb" goes under 450 on the y axis, it is supposed to be deleted.

```
import pygame
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREY = (129, 129, 129)

class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, colour):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.set_colorkey(colour)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x =0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Untitled.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 2, 48, 48, WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def move(self, y):
        self.rect.y += y
        if self.rect.y > 450:
            self.kill()
        print (self.rect.y)
pygame.init()
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
bomb  = Bomb()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(bomb)
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    bomb.move(2)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

(Note that I'm printing the y axis of the bomb to check if it's deleted or not.) I tried to use the "kill()" method, but what happens is, it **does** disappear, but the y axis continues to print, which I think is not supposed to happen.

I tried to use the kill() method in another piece of code. It gets deleted and the y axis stops printing. The only difference between the 2 codes is that in this one, I am blitting an image onto the screen to use as a sprite, and in that one, I am using "Rect" to make the sprite.

Can someone please guide me on what else can I do to permanently remove the sprite from the memory, or is it okay if the values of the y axis are printing all the time (the sprite should be deleted)?

Answer (score 2):

The [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) method does not magically remove objects from memory. All it does is removing a Sprite from all it's Groups.

So in your code, the bomb is no longer displayed because it's no longer in `all_sprites` after `kill()` is called. But you still have a reference to the object (`bomb`), and you still call the `move` function every frame on the object. So the `print` statement is executed.

What do you expect to happen to your `bomb` variable after you called `kill()`?

Usually, you should implement all sprite logic in a method called [`update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update), and not call this method directly, but via the group, too, like the `draw` method.

Something like this:

```
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x =0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Untitled.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 2, 48, 48, WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed = 2
    def update(self, y):
        self.rect.y += self.speed
        if self.rect.y > 450:
            self.kill()
        print (self.rect.y)

...
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(Bomb())
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    all_sprites.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

This way, after `kill()` is called, no references to the object remain (and the python runtime will remove it from memory eventually).

Comment: I understand that, but is there any way I can permanently remove it from the memory?

Comment: As I said in my answer, don't keep another reference to that object. Use groups to manage your sprites.

Comment: I'm already using groups. Can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: If I do this, (all_sprites.add(Bomb() ), 1. Will I be able to create multiple of these bombs at the same time? 2. How can I call the functions defined in the class?